# jQuery and set the state of the button

Tags: jquery

The page contains 1 checkBox, 3 Radio Buttons and a button. If the state of the checkBox or any of Radio Buttons is changed it should be enabled. As the page loads, the button is disabled by default.

The code below doesn't work for radio buttons, but it works for checkBox. Where is the mistake?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /*The initial values of checkBox and RadioButtons they have as the page was loaded*/
    var rbl = $('#rbgList').find('input:radio:checked');
    var rblInitialValue = rbl.val();

    var chk = $('#chkHideFromAddressBook');
    var chkInitialValue = chk.is(":checked");

    var btn = $('#btnSaveConfigSettings');

    var isChanged = function () {
        return ((rbl.val() != rblInitialValue) || (chk.is(":checked") != chkInitialValue));
    };

    /*Set button the state of SaveChanges to enables/disabled that depends on of the current state (check/unchecked) of checkBox and RadioButtons*/

    /*1*/
    $('#rbgList input:radio').click(function () {
        isChanged() ? btn.attr('disabled', '') : btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });


    /*2*/
    $("#chkHideFromAddressBook").click(function () {
        isChanged() ? btn.attr('disabled', '') : btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

})
```

**But this one works well**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /*The initial values of checkBox and RadioButtons they have as the page was loaded*/
    var rblInitialValue = $('#rbgList').find('input:radio:checked').val();
    var chkInitialValue = $('#chkHideFromAddressBook').is(":checked");


    $('#rbgList input:radio').click(function () {
        if (
                ($('#rbgList').find('input:radio:checked').val() != rblInitialValue) ||
                ($('#chkHideFromAddressBook').is(":checked") != chkInitialValue)
            ) {
            $('#btnSaveConfigSettings').attr('disabled', '');
        }
        else {
            $('#btnSaveConfigSettings').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });



    $("#chkHideFromAddressBook").click(function () {
        if (
                ($('#rbgList').find('input:radio:checked').val() != rblInitialValue) ||
                ($('#chkHideFromAddressBook').is(":checked") != chkInitialValue)
            ) {
            $('#btnSaveConfigSettings').attr('disabled', '');
        }
        else {
            $('#btnSaveConfigSettings').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: would it help if you have the radio event on the change rather than the click? that way you could see specifically if it is changed.

Comment: @Geoist Click will also provide you with the target element, and therefore the radio/checkbox state (in this case). However, the `change` event - unlike the `click` event - will trigger when using the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this:

```
var rbl = $('#rbgList').find('input:radio:checked');
var rblInitialValue = rbl.val();
```

While that code is fine in terms of syntax, `rbl` doesn't update when you check a different radio button, and as a result this test:

```
(rbl.val() != rblInitialValue)
```

will always evaluate to `false`.

You'll need to get a new reference to the checked radio button when the value changes, so that you're comparing the value of the currently checked radio button against the value of the initially checked radio button. The least modification to your existing code would be:

```
$('#rbgList input:radio').click(function () {
    rbl = $(this);
    isChanged() ? btn.attr('disabled', '') : btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: As far as I'm concerned it shouldn't be updated when I check a different radio button. Why? I'm not savvy.

Comment: Hmmm, it works as I want but in fact I don't understand why. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know you didn't ask for a whole solution, but I got sidetracked fixing it up.  Here it is anyway.

#### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/UHXf2/2/

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var originalindex = -1;
    var originalcheck = -1;
    var button;
    var check;

    function getindex() {
        return $('input[name=sex]:checked', '#myform').index();
    }

    function getcheck() {
        return check.is(':checked');
    }

    function validateform() {
        if (getindex() == originalindex && getcheck() == originalcheck) {
            button.attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            button.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }

    button = $('input[name=submit]', '#myform');
    check = $('input[name=alien]', '#myform');

    originalindex = getindex();
    originalcheck = getcheck();

    $('input[name=sex]', '#myform').change(function() {
        validateform();
    });
    check.change(function() {
        validateform();
    });

});​
```

#### HTML

```
<form id="myform">
 <input type="radio" name="sex" value="m" checked="true" /> Male<br />
 <input type="radio" name="sex" value="f" /> Female<br />
 <input type="radio" name="sex" value="o" /> Other<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="alien" value="h" checked="false" /> Human<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" disabled="true" />
</form>​
```

Comment: `checked="false"` results in a checkbox that is checked.